# Newtonsoft.Json требует сделать json массив, но после указания json массива требует еще один

Tags: c#, json, json.net

В названии белиберда, но это так.

Я компилирую проект - получаю исключение

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException" в Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Исключение типа "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException" возникло в Newtonsoft.Json.dll, но не было обработано в коде пользователя
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[vOverlay.Player][]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'user', line 1, position 8
```

Хорошо, я указал массив заменив `List<Player> ply = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Player>>(json);` на `List<Player>[] ply = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Player>[]>(json);`. Иии... Все тоже исключение...

[Отрывок кода на pastebin](https://pastebin.com/mWfuP27Q)

[API](https://api.vimeworld.ru/user/134568/stats)

p.s: В классе `Player` есть вложенный класс `user` потому что я его использую для двух функций, формат апи изменяется минимально - добавляется только коллекция `"user"`

Comment: Начните с изучения [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). Вот ещё: [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), [2](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Ведь вы же изучали C#, прежде чем начать его использовать? Так почему большинство не изучают json, xml, csv и прочие форматы данных, прежде чем начать их использовать?

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но вопрос заключается в  проблеме - не работает код выше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ошибке ясно сказано:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[vOverlay.Player][]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

То есть в json имеется **объект**: `{"name":"value"}` - обратите внимание на **фигурные** скобки. А вы в коде C# указали коллекцию `List<T>` (aka массив).

Для определения **массива** в json используются **квадратные** скобки. Коллекция (массив) в коде должна соответствовать коллекции (массиву) в json.

В тексте ошибки ясно сказано, что нужно сделать:

> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List)

Уберите коллекцию из кода C#!
А вы наоборот добавляете ещё одну.

Вместо `List<Player>` должен быть просто `Player`.

---

И ради всего святого, давайте нормальные имена! Что такое `ply`? Вы сами сможете сказать, не зная контекста?
Вот же: `Player player` - простое и понятное именование.
`List<Player> players` - множественное число для коллекции.

Comment: Player - ply, это можно сказать не зная контекста, подобное сокращение часто используется в игровом скриптинге

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, поддерживаю, ничего святого) ply - складка?